# Handling response after httppost in java

Tags: java, httpclient

I am using httpclient to post a xml in java.  I am also expecting a xml in response.
How do I parse the response as xml?

This is what I have so far

```
HttpClient cliet = HttpClientFactory.getClient("mhurl.com");
...
PostMethod post;
post.setRquestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(myxml_in_string,"xml",...);
...
int result = client.executeMethod(post);
InputStream in = post.getRespoinseBodyAsStream();
?? //Not sure how to handle the response from here
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Standard Java DOM API:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(in);
```

Last line is crucial.

## SAX API

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
saxParser.parse(in, yourCustomCallback);
```

## JAXB

Assuming you have appropriate models:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
Response response = (Response)context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(in);
```

Comment: Oh okay, I think I will stay with standard DOM. Thanks for your help.